# Correcting Modified Collection Exception for a CheckBox Change Event

Tags: c#, winforms, revit-api

I have a problem where Checkboxes are dynamically created and each subscribes to an event. When the checkBox is checked, it selects supports of a beam. when unchecked, elements that are not supports are deselected. The issue is the collection property gives me a modified collection exception....

```
List<ElementId> elementIds = new List<ElementId>();
public List<ElementId> ElementIds { get; set; }

private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UIDocument uidoc = new UIDocument(document);
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
            
            if (checkBox.Checked)
            {
                Element element = supportelements.FirstOrDefault(q => q.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.ALL_MODEL_MARK).AsString() == GetMark(checkBox));

                if (elementIds.Any(q => q.Equals(element.Id)))
                    return;
                else
                {
                    elementIds.Add(element.Id);
                    ICollection<ElementId> Ids = new List<ElementId>() { element.Id };
                    uidoc.Selection.SetElementIds(Ids);
                    uidoc.RefreshActiveView();
                }

                ElementIds = elementIds;
            }
            else if (!checkBox.Checked)
            {
                ElementId invalid = ElementId.InvalidElementId;
                List<ElementId> invalidList = new List<ElementId>
                {
                    invalid
                };

                uidoc.Selection.SetElementIds(invalidList);
                uidoc.RefreshActiveView();

                if (ElementIds != null)
                {
                    ElementId elementId = supportelements.FirstOrDefault(q => q.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.ALL_MODEL_MARK).AsString() == GetMark(checkBox)).Id;
                    elementIds.Remove(elementId);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your statements above is calling `SetElementIds(invalidList)`.

Think about what that means.

E.g., you are telling Revit, 'Hey, look, here is an invalid element. Please select and highlight it on the screen for me.'

If I were Revit, I would refuse.

How about simply providing an empty list of element ids instead, and saying, 'Here are zero elements. Please select and highlight those.'

I can imagine that might work better.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, an empty collection works fine as you suggested so the invalid list has been done away with.. The modified collection was in a subsequent method and has been traced. Thank you..

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation and appreciation. My pleasure entirely.